# pgbouncer logs filled with warning

Tags: logging, warnings, pgbouncer

I am seeing below warnings in the pgbouncer logs. I am using pgbouncer 1.7.2 in session pooling mode.

```
FIXME: query end, but query_start == 0
```

Could you please help in understanding this warning and how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score -1):

This is possibly fixed with this [pull request](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/pull/253).